# connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed

Tags: django, postgresql

I am facing this error "OperationalError at /results/
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?" when I try to run a django application that I just deployed in railway.app.
What is the problem and how can I fix?

When I run the application locally it works well, it is my first time deploying a django application to production and I have no idea how to solve that issue, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too little information to answer. We don't even know if the application is on the same machine as the database or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the error is due to not using railway's database. Apparently it was running localhost and my postgres' port, created a postgres database in railway and connected to the deployed django app and it is now working well. Thank you @Laurenz Albe for reminding me that.